# AccessViolationException Quando eu digito ALT ou TAB C# WINDOWS FORM

Tags: c#, winforms, thread

Galera, eu tenho uns forms onde o Form (Plano_Aula) chama o form (Chamada) , nesse Form Chamada tem uma lista de alunos e um Painel que fica com o  visible = false, nessa mesma tela chamo um classe onde faz  reconhecimento facial em outra Thread, mas o problema é o seguinte, quando eu seto esse painel visible = true pela thread de reconhecimento facial, eu posso apertar qualquer tecla , mas quando aperto ALT ou TAB Recebo exception

Vejam as telas,

Chamada com o painel visible = false :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tornando - o True

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu aperto ALT ou TAB vejam

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já resolvi o problema